# Siphash tostring and getBytes()

Tags: java, string, byte, guava

I have generated SipHash for 1 string and 2 long values (for many such combinations of string and long). I used -

```
Hasher hash = Hashing.sipHash24().newHasher().putUnencodedChars("abcd").putLong(123).putLong(123);
```

Now I converted this hash to string using -

```
String hashString = hash.hash().toString();
```

But, I wanted the bytes array of the string, Could there be any way, so that I am able to get the bytes array from this string same as to the one I would have got from `byte[] hashBytes = hash.hash().asBytes();` I wanted to convert the string I had got from these hashes to bytes array.

Actually I realised that the bytes array was using only 8 bytes of space for the siphash, where as the length of string was 18 bytes. So , I guess storing the hash as bytes array would be more optimised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().decode(string)
```

should convert `HashCode.toString()` back into the byte array you would've gotten from `asBytes()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the string back into a `HashCode` instance with `HashCode.fromString(string)`. Then you can call `.asBytes()` on the `HashCode` instance to get back a copy of the underlying `byte[]`.

So basically you want:

`byte[] bytes = HashCode.fromString(string).asBytes();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get bytes array from string -

```
public static byte[] getBytes(String hashString) {

    final byte[] bytes = new byte[8];

    HashMap<Character, String> bin = new HashMap<>();
    bin.put('0', "0000");
    bin.put('1', "0001");
    bin.put('2', "0010");
    bin.put('3', "0011");
    bin.put('4', "0100");
    bin.put('5', "0101");
    bin.put('6', "0110");
    bin.put('7', "0111");
    bin.put('8', "1000");
    bin.put('9', "1001");
    bin.put('a', "1010");
    bin.put('b', "1011");
    bin.put('c', "1100");
    bin.put('d', "1101");
    bin.put('e', "1110");
    bin.put('f', "1111");

    for (int i = 0; i < 16 && i < hashString.length(); i += 2) {

        final BitSet bitset = new BitSet(8);
        String byteBinary = bin.get(hashString.charAt(i)) + bin.get(hashString.charAt(i + 1));
        for (int j = 0; j<8; j++) {

            if (byteBinary.charAt(j) == '1')
                bitset.set(7-j, true);
            else
                bitset.set(7-j, false);
        }


        bytes[i/2] = bitset.toByteArray()[0];
        //System.out.println(byteBinary);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```